# How does shadow-cljs handle duplicates of the same dependency with difference versions on the shadow-cljs.edn file?

Tags: clojure, versioning, dependency-management, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame,
reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic
web app project.

In my `shadow-cljs.edn`, I have:

```
{:source-paths ["src" "dev"]

 :dependencies [[testdouble/clojurescript.csv "0.5.2-LOCAL-FORK"]
                [testdouble/clojurescript.csv "0.5.1"]]
                
                .
                .
                .
```

As you see, there is a duplicate of the same dependency being used two
times.

How does shadow-cljs treat this?

Are both dependencies compiled? One over the other?

Just the latest one or the last one to be displayed on the file?

Comment: What is the point of this? Are you asking, how conflicting transitive deps are handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library can only be added once, due to how the [classpath](https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2021/05/13/paths-paths-paths.html) works. In case of `:dependencies` in `shadow-cljs.edn` it'll pick the first one found.

But really you shouldn't ever use two versions of the same lib. It may have unexpected results and should be avoided. In fact I'm a little surprised that doesn't already throw an error.